# Python pandas how to optimizes comparing rows of a dataframe?

Tags: python, for-loop, optimization, pandas

I have a large dataframe with 169361 rows and I would like to compare the rows pairwise for all the rows.
My dataframe:

```
new_org         old_org                 asn     cc
85736 pcizzi    85736 - Pcizzi S .a     23201   PY
001             001 Host                40244   US
001             001 IT Complex          55734   IN
001 hospedagem  001 Hospedagem Ltda     36351   US
001web          action.us.001web.net    36351   US
```

and In my code I am comparing content of the column "new_org" and 'asn' pairwise, and if they are the same I put a "match" tag 
`my code`:.

```
matching_dic = []    
tuples = [tuple(x) for x in df_compare.values]
# tuples

for i in range(len(tuples)):
    for j in range(i+1, len(tuples)):
        if tuples[i][1]!=tuples[j][1]:
            compare = str(tuples[i][0]) + '|' + str(tuples[j][0])
            originals_asn = str(tuples[i][2]) + '|' + str(tuples[j][2])
            originals_cc = str(tuples[i][3]) + '|' + str(tuples[j][3])
            if tuples[i][0]==tuples[j][0]:
                if tuples[i][2]==tuples[j][2]:
                    first_tag = 'match'
                    matching_dic.append({'originals_asn':originals_asn,'originals_cc':originals_cc, 'compare': compare, 'first_tag': first_tag})

dftest = DataFrame(matching_dic)
```

Here is the `Expected result`:

```
compare              first_tag  originals_asn   originals_cc    
001 hospedagem|001web   match   3595|3595         US|US
```

It is working perfectly now for 1000 rows as test but it takes a long time for the whole dataset. Does anybody know a more efficient way ?

Comment: as an idea, I'd group dataset by `asn` and then just created ouput for all groups which have more than one row

Comment: Of course it will take a long time; there are 14.3 billion possible pairwise combinations.

Comment: I tried a different approach than @RomanPekar but that does seem like a good suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

A bit of a hack, but I think it ought to be a bit faster than what you are currently doing (one way to find out).  I duplicated one row to better check that it works OK (so below you can see that rows 0 and 2 match along with 4 and 5):

```
          new_org               old_org    asn  cc
0    85736 pcizzi   85736 - Pcizzi S .a  23201  PY
1             001              001 Host  40244  US
2      85736 blah       85736 - whatevs  23201  PY
3             001        001 IT Complex  55734  IN
4  001 hospedagem   001 Hospedagem Ltda  36351  US
5          001web  action.us.001web.net  36351  US
```

Anyway, if it's a useful approach (and fast enough) it could certainly be cleaned up further.

```
org, asn, cc = [], [], []

for i in range(1,len(df)):
    df2 = df.iloc[i:].reset_index(drop=True)
    df3 = df.iloc[:-i]
    mask = df2.asn == df3.asn
        if any(mask):
        org.append( [ df2.new_org[mask].values[0], df3.new_org[mask].values[0] ] )
        asn.append(   df2.asn[mask].values[0] )
        cc.append(    df2.cc[mask].values[0] )

matches = pd.concat( [pd.DataFrame(org, columns=['org1','org2']),
                      pd.DataFrame(asn, columns=['asn']),
                      pd.DataFrame(cc,  columns=['cc']),], axis=1 )

matches

         org1            org2    asn  cc
0      001web  001 hospedagem  36351  US
1  85736 blah    85736 pcizzi  23201  PY
```